# sum condition applied on possible permutations of a vector without a loop MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to sum the following condition to sum the following condition for an array of size `n`:

For example `n=4`

```
eps=0.6;    
((x(1)<eps && x(2)<eps && x(3)<eps) || ...
(x(1)<eps && x(2)<eps && x(4)<eps) || ...
(x(2)<eps && x(3)<eps && x(4)<eps) || ...
(x(1)<eps && x(3)<eps && x(4)<eps))
```

for `x=[0.1 0.5 0.3 0.9]` the results will be `s=1` and for `x=[0.1 0.6 0.7 0.9]` the result will be `s=0`

how can this be done without using a double loop?

Comment: Your question is unclear. See if my answer is what you want, and in any case please edit your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to form combinations of `N` elements from `x` and see how many of those combinations have all their elements less than `eps`:

```
x = [0.1 0.5 0.3 0.9]; % vector with at least two elements
N = 3; % number of elements in each combination
epsilon = 0.6; % threshold

combs = nchoosek(x, N); % N-column matrix where each row is a combination
result = sum(all(combs < epsilon, 2)); % number of combinations fulfilling the criterion
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your condition as:

```
condition = (sum(x >= eps) == 1);
```

for any size of x. Basically you just check if there is only one element that is not smaller than eps.

Comment: Since you need to check that 3 of them are less than eps, you can more easily check if only one is bigger than that. But I just noticed that I had mistakingly set < instead of >.